# How to delete the white space in the end of the line?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, editor

The is the code :

```
POST http://api.ltp-cloud.com/analysis/ HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d6172632-c912-43f0-9af7-8a8decd0c0e2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/6.2.5
Accept: */*
Host: api.ltp-cloud.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 760
Connection: keep-alive

text =%3Cxml4nlp%3E%3Cnote+lstmsemparser%3D%22n%22+ne%3D%22n%22+parser%3D%22n%22+pos%3D%22n%22+semparser%3D%22n%22+sent%3D%22y%22+srl%3D%22n%22+word%3D%22y%22+%2F%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cpara+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Csent+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%E7%9A%84%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%22+id%3D%220%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%22+id%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%22+id%3D%222%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%9A%84%22+id%3D%223%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%224%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fsent%3E%3C%2Fpara%3E%3C%2Fdoc%3E%3C%2Fxml4nlp%3E&api_key=x1e3E1Z3H4AzgRQolEGE8PxHlCEXtTnDbJvkjw5p&pattern=ws&xml_input=true&format=plain
```

It shows up like this in the SE editor:

> [image]

How do I make it show up on the same line without the space between `text` and `=`?

[image]

Comment: How is this relevant on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Using stack exchange,there is some white space I can't type.What the aim of this site?

Comment: You go to that piece of code in your post and remove it. It's really that simple.

Comment: @Werner you can try it.The text will move to the next line.

Comment: Why upvote me? what the purpose of this meta site... Isn't a place where people can solve the problem using the Stack Exchange.

Comment: This seems very much like an issue of not having *tried* to solve your problem; As explained in the answer, all you needed to do was actually *try* to delete the character. This site is for questions pertaining to the Stack Exchange network, but questions that show no research effort *will* be downvoted. It's even in the roll-over text, when you roll-over the downvote button.

Comment: @Gnemlock Thank you.This is my first time to go here and this question really make me confused long time...  I will read more info about this site and contribute more...

Comment: Please feel free to also check out the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). This area lets you have a good play around with formatting, to check things like this, and discover new features. Enjoy

Comment: @Gnemlock sure,thanks.  And the atmosphere here are really good...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code with the space:

```
<snip>

text =%3Cxml4nlp%3E%3Cnote+lstmsemparser%3D%22n%22+ne%3D%22n%22+parser%3D%22n%22+pos%3D%22n%22+semparser%3D%22n%22+sent%3D%22y%22+srl%3D%22n%22+word%3D%22y%22+%2F%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cpara+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Csent+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%E7%9A%84%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%22+id%3D%220%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%22+id%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%22+id%3D%222%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%9A%84%22+id%3D%223%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%224%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fsent%3E%3C%2Fpara%3E%3C%2Fdoc%3E%3C%2Fxml4nlp%3E&api_key=x1e3E1Z3H4AzgRQolEGE8PxHlCEXtTnDbJvkjw5p&pattern=ws&xml_input=true&format=plain
```

This is the code without the space:

```
<snip>

text=%3Cxml4nlp%3E%3Cnote+lstmsemparser%3D%22n%22+ne%3D%22n%22+parser%3D%22n%22+pos%3D%22n%22+semparser%3D%22n%22+sent%3D%22y%22+srl%3D%22n%22+word%3D%22y%22+%2F%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cpara+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Csent+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%E7%9A%84%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%22+id%3D%220%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%22+id%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%22+id%3D%222%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%9A%84%22+id%3D%223%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%224%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fsent%3E%3C%2Fpara%3E%3C%2Fdoc%3E%3C%2Fxml4nlp%3E&api_key=x1e3E1Z3H4AzgRQolEGE8PxHlCEXtTnDbJvkjw5p&pattern=ws&xml_input=true&format=plain
```

It wasn't difficult at all. Find the space, press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and it disappears. Sure it displays as being on a line *below* where it should be, but that's only in the input side. The "baked" (output) side shows up as expected.

Comment: wow.... I am not recognize this problem before..Thank you indeed